# SQLite: Why can't I DETACH a database when the main DB has an open prepared statement?

Tags: c, sqlite

Why does the following Code not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(void)
{
    sqlite3 *pDb;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *errmsg;

    sqlite3_open(":memory:", &pDb);

    sqlite3_exec(pDb, "CREATE TABLE Test(a INTEGER)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    sqlite3_exec(pDb, "INSERT INTO Test(a) VALUES(1)", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, "SELECT * FROM Test", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);

    sqlite3_exec(pDb, "ATTACH 'Test.db' as Other;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_exec(pDb, "DETACH Other;", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    printf("error: %s\n", errmsg);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
error: database Other is locked
```

If I do a `sqlite3_reset(stmt)` after the `sqlite3_step(stmt)`, it works.

Why does an open statement on an unrelated database lock the "Other" database? I couldn't find an explanation in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [transaction documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) says:

> An implicit transaction (a transaction that is started automatically, not a transaction started by BEGIN) is committed automatically when the last active statement finishes. A statement finishes when its prepared statement is [reset](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) or [finalized](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html).

Transactions always [affect all attached databases](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html#multicommit), so an open transaction will keep all databases locked.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light on this. That's really hidden. I guess it's a good practice to reset() all statements once they're no longer needed...